# How do I make it so that any part of a background image that is under an svg has a duotone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mask

I have a background image and want to have a border around the screen that has a duotone of the image, (not a manually edited duotone made in photoshop, I plan on animating this) how would I achieve this so that any part of the background image that is underneath a certain svg is affected by this?  I plan on animating the svg so that it moves, and the parts of the image that ARE duotone change.

This is an example of the duotone:

```css
body {
  background: #1d1f20;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.svg-filters {
  height: 0;
  left: -9999em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.img {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 350px;
}

hr {
  border: solid 1px #191919;
}

.duotoned--peachy {
  filter: url('#duotone_peachypink');
}

.duotoned--navy {
  filter: url('#duotone_navyorange');
}
```

```html
<!-- Duotone Article Demo -->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-filters">
  <filter id="duotone_peachypink">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
    
    <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_magenta_gold">
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.3411764706 0.1082352941"></feFuncR>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0431372549 0.7333333333"></feFuncG>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.568627451 0.05098039216"></feFuncB>
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
    </feComponentTransfer> 
  </filter>
  
  <filter id="duotone_navyorange">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0" />
    
    <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_navy_orange">
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.05490196078 1"></feFuncR>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.1568627451 0.5921568627"></feFuncG>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.1647058824 0.003921568627"></feFuncB>
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
    </feComponentTransfer> 
  </filter>   
</svg>

<img class="img" src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127610/sifnos-chrisopigi.png' alt='Original Image'>

<img class="img duotoned--peachy" src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127610/sifnos-chrisopigi.png' alt='Duotoned Image'>

<hr>

<img class="img" src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127610/jardin-majorelle-small.jpg' alt='Original Image'>

<img class="img duotoned--navy" src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127610/jardin-majorelle-small.jpg' alt='Duotoned Imaged'>
```

This photo attached is a manual background I created in photoshop, and the example of the effect I want to achieve.  The goal is to have it so the top of the border moves down and that anything within the border as it moves down is duotone.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV1PR.jpg)

edit:
For example, [here](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/fsdbu), the third example has only the part of the image inside the star showing.  what I want is so only the part of the image inside an svg has a duotone effect.

Comment: the code you posted shows two lots of two images ... what isn't clear (to me) is, what do you want?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's just an example of duotones.  What I want is a mask so that anything underneath the svg has a duotone effect.  The image in the background is black and white, but I want any part of the image that is underneath an svg to be duotone.  So in the first duotone in the code I provided, what I would want is so that only part of the image is actually duotone.  for example, [here](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/fsdbu ), the third example has only the part of the image inside the star showing.  what I want is so only the part of the image inside an svg has a duotone effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to stack the two images on top of one another, then apply a sppropriately-shaped clip to the top one.

```css
body {
  background: #1d1f20;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.svg-filters {
  height: 0;
  left: -9999em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.img {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 350px;
}

hr {
  border: solid 1px #191919;
}

.duotoned--peachy {
  filter: url('#duotone_peachypink');
}

.diamond-clip {
  clip-path: url(#diamond-clip);
}

.stack {
  position: relative;
}

.stack img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Duotone Article Demo -->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-filters">
  <filter id="duotone_peachypink">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
    
    <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_magenta_gold">
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.3411764706 0.1082352941"></feFuncR>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0431372549 0.7333333333"></feFuncG>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.568627451 0.05098039216"></feFuncB>
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
    </feComponentTransfer> 
  </filter>
  
  <clipPath id="diamond-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0.5,0, 1,0.5, 0.5,1, 0,0.5"/>
  </clipPath>

</svg>

<div class="stack">
  <img class="img" src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127610/sifnos-chrisopigi.png' alt='Original Image'>
  <img class="img duotoned--peachy diamond-clip"
                   src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127610/sifnos-chrisopigi.png' alt='Duotoned Image'>
</div>
```